# Acessar valores de um json em python

Tags: python, json

Tenho o seguinte código em python

```
import requests
import json

data = requests.get('https://proxycheck.io/v2/42.131.121.100?vpn=1&asn=1')

print(data.text)
```

Que vai retornar:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "42.131.121.100": {
        "continent": "Asia",
        "country": "China",
        "isocode": "CN",
        "latitude": 34.7725,
        "longitude": 113.7266,
        "proxy": "no",
        "type": "Business"
    }
}
```

Como faço para exibir apenas o que está em "country"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você quer trabalhar com json, ao invés de utilizar `data.text` utilize `data.json`

```
import requests

data = requests.get('https://proxycheck.io/v2/42.131.121.100?vpn=1&asn=1')
j = data.json()

j['42.131.121.100']['country']
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o seguinte código para acessar o obj "42.131.121.100":

```
print(data.text["42.131.121.100"]["country"])
```

Comment: Como você está indexando as chaves se `data.text` é uma string?

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
import json


#Pode-se utilizar dicionario python para acessar conteudo no formato json
#Acessar conteudo por chaves ou valores.
#para acessar só indicar a chave  
# exemplo
#item["country"],item["continent"]

for item in json.loads(requests.get('https://proxycheck.io/v2/42.131.121.100?vpn=1&asn=1').text).values():
  if item  != "ok":
   print(item["country"])
```