# Acessar valores JSON com PHP

Tags: php, json

Tenho a seguinte API: https://proxycheck.io/v2/42.131.121.100?vpn=1&asn=1

```
{
"status": "ok",
"42.131.121.100": {
    "continent": "Asia",
    "country": "China",
    "isocode": "CN",
    "latitude": 34.7732,
    "longitude": 113.722,
    "proxy": "no",
    "type": "Business"
    }
}
```

Como faço para acessar apenas o que está em "country" e "type" e colocar em uma variável?

Comment: sempre vai ser assim? esse layout muda em alguma momento, ou essa pesquisa api muda os parametros?

Comment: sempre assim, o layout sempre vai ser o mesmo

Comment: como os mesmos valores, por exemplo `42.131.121.100` sempre vai ser esse número?

Comment: Esse valor vai mudar de acordo com o que for passado no link da API, mas pro exemplo podemos levar em consideração um valor fixo nesse IP sempre.

Comment: Tem que escrever um código que se encaixe em vários aspectos. complicado até responder

Comment: Não sei se ajuda, mas em Python seria assim:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/486831/acessar-valores-de-um-json-em-python

Preciso fazer a mesma coisa, só que em PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente, após o resgate dessa informação com [curl](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php) do [php](/questions/tagged/php) transformar em [array](/questions/tagged/array) com [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php) e depois passar as chaves em sequencia como descrita no `layout` do [json](/questions/tagged/json), *exemplo de código*:

```
<?php
    $url = 'https://proxycheck.io/v2/42.131.121.100?vpn=1&asn=1';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $json = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if ($httpCode === 200) {
        $array = json_decode($json, TRUE);
        $country = $array['42.131.121.100']['country'];
        $type = $array['42.131.121.100']['type'];
    }
    curl_close($ch);
```